# How can I show a single parameter's Javadoc?

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

Often when looking at method calls with many parameters, I'd like to know what a particular parameter's Javadoc without counting the number of commas, then going to the declaration and counting again.

How can I directly view the Javadoc for a particular parameter from the client method call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse does not support this, and I've filed an [enhancement request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=387078).

> Suppose I have the following code:
>
> ```
> void foo(int i) {}
> void bar() {
>    foo(1);
> }
> ```
>
> If I hover over the 1, I would like to see "int i" as I do if I hover
>   over "foo".  I know this can conflict with showing the Javadocs of
>   methods or fields in the parameter such as how presently Eclipse shows
>   on hover the Javadoc for random() below:
>
> ```
> void bar() {
>    foo(random());
> }
> ```
>
> Perhaps there could be a hover modifier key to override this and a
>   precedence order to determine which Javadoc is displayed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a workaround/similar feature is:

`foo(34, bar1, [cursor]bar2)`

press ctrl-space

This shows the method signature above with the formal parameter corresponding to bar2 highlighted.

(this works in juno at least)

Comment: It would be a great workaround since usually the parameter names are self-documenting, but there's no highlighting of the parameter (bar2 in your example) in Indigo.